# Samba is not working but smbclient does

Tags: networking, server, windows, samba, file-sharing

I want to explore my windows network but Samba isn't working on nautilus or thunar.
These are the characteristics

- The icon Windows Network is there. But if i try to open it keeps on "Opening <> forever.
- On Nautilus if i try to put "smb://serverIP/folder", it shows me an login windows, but as soon as i click on connect, it says that it failed to mount the windows folder and gives me the message: the file alredy exist.
- smb4k doesn't detect anything.
- If i do smbclient \\ServerPC\Folder it works!
- I tried to change the configuration file /etc/samba/smb.conf but it doesn't work. then i use gadminSamba to generate a new file and doesn't work eigther... So i change it a bit there is

```
    [global]
netbios name = Samba24
server string = Samba file and print server
workgroup = workgroup
client lanman auth = yes
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
security = user
hosts allow = 192.168.111.1
interfaces = wlp2s0 192.168.111.0/8
bind interfaces only = yes
remote announce = wlp2s0 192.168.111.255
remote browse sync = wlp2s0 192.168.111.255
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
printing = cups
guest account = smbguest
log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
max log size = 1000
username level = 6
encrypt passwords = yes
unix password sync = yes
local master = no
domain master = no
preferred master = no
domain logons = no
os level = 33
logon drive = m:
logon home = \\%L\homes\%u
logon path = \\%L\profiles\%u
logon script = %G.bat
time server = no
name resolve order = wins lmhosts bcast
wins support = yes
wins proxy = no
dns proxy = no
preserve case = yes
short preserve case = yes
client use spnego = no
client signing = no
client schannel = no
server signing = no
server schannel = no
nt pipe support = yes
nt status support = yes
allow trusted domains = no
obey pam restrictions = yes
enable spoolss = yes
client plaintext auth = no
disable netbios = no
follow symlinks = no
pam password change = no
passwd chat timeout = 120
hostname lookups = no
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
passdb backend = tdbsam
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd '%u'
passwd chat = *New*password* %n\n *ReType*new*password* %n\n *passwd*changed*\n
add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -c 'Samba User Account' -s /dev/null '%u'
add user to group script = /usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -c 'Samba User Account' -s /dev/null -g '%g' '%u'
add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd '%g'
delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel '%u'
delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/userdel '%u' '%g'
delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel '%g'
add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -d /dev/null -g sambamachines -c 'Samba Machine Account' -s /dev/null -M '%u'
machine password timeout = 120
template shell = /dev/null
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind separator = @
winbind cache time = 360
winbind trusted domains only = yes
winbind nested groups = no
winbind nss info = no
winbind refresh tickets = no
winbind offline logon = no

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
path = /home
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no

[netlogon]
comment = Network Logon Service
path = /home/netlogon
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no

[profiles]
comment = User Profiles
path = /var/samba/profiles
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = no
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
create mode = 0600
directory mask = 0700
locking = no
strict locking = no

[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = yes
locking = no
strict locking = no

[pdf-documents]
path = /home/pdf-documents
comment = Converted PDF Documents
available = yes
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
locking = no
strict locking = no

[pdf-printer]
path = /tmp
comment = PDF Printer Service
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
use client driver = yes
printing = bsd
print command = /usr/bin/gadmin-samba-pdf %s %u
lpq command =
lprm command =
```

notes:

- wlp2s0 is my wifi interface
- The server ip is 192.168.111.1
- The server is working as dhcp server and as WiFi acces point.
- I can access to the windows network through another windows pc... or even from an android phone!